# How do I import data via a Bluetooth connection on an android app, even in the background?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I have a few questions in regards to Bluetooth usage on android apps

1 - How can a Bluetooth connection be used to import and use data, even when a device is in sleep or the app is in the background? Is there a way to do this in a way that is battery/power efficient for the device?

2 - Is there a way to detect what kind of Bluetooth device(s) are connected?

Sorry if these are dumb questions and thanks in advance for answering!